# Install Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop

Tags: boot, system-installation, 18.04, fedora

I have Fedora 20 installed in my laptop. I want to move on from Fedora 20 to Ubuntu 18.04.

Is it necessary to boot to windows first or can I directly boot Ubuntu 18.04 on my Fedora 20 by USB boot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) If your computer has Windows pre-installed with UEFI firmware see [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 0):

No, windows is not needed for this.